# LIBSSH2 C++ with dual stack IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: c++, ipv6, libssh2

I am working on a C++ project that needs to establish a connection via SSH to a remote server and execute some commands and transfer files via SFTP. However, I need this application to work in dual stack mode (e.g., with IPv6 and IPv4) mode.

In the snippet below, my program initially receives an host-name, IPv6 or IPv4 address. In the IPv4 input the connection is successful. However, I am having strange problems in the IPv6 mode that I am noticing that the connection is established via socket and the SSH session fails to start.

Currently, I believe it could be something related to the inet_ntop() method. Please notice that remoteHost variable is an char* type and the remotePort is uint16_t type.

```
// Initialize some important variables
uint32_t hostaddr = 0, hostaddr6 = 0;
struct sockaddr_in sin = {};
struct sockaddr_in6 sinV6 = {};
int rc = 0, sock = 0, i = 0, auth_pw = 0;

// Here we will initialize our base class with username and password
this->username = usrName;
this->password = usrPassword;

// Firstly, we need to translate the hostname into an IPv4 or IPv6 address
struct addrinfo hints={}, *sAdrInfo = {};
char addrstr[100]={};
void *ptr= nullptr;
char addrParsed[50]={};

memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (hints));
hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags |= AI_CANONNAME;

// Now we need to get some address info from the one supplied that remoteHost parameter
int errcode = getaddrinfo (remoteHost, nullptr, &hints, &sAdrInfo);
if (errcode != 0) {
    SERVER_ERROR("[SSH] Error while getaddrinfo at SSHConnect() code %d", errno);
    return -4;
}

inet_ntop(sAdrInfo->ai_family, sAdrInfo->ai_addr->sa_data, addrstr, 100);

// Here we need to determine if we are using IPv6 or IPv4
switch (sAdrInfo->ai_family) {
    case AF_INET6:
        ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *) sAdrInfo->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
        break;
    case AF_INET:
        ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in *) sAdrInfo->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
        break;
}
inet_ntop(sAdrInfo->ai_family, ptr, addrstr, 100);
sprintf(addrParsed, "%s", addrstr);

//This part is responsible for creating the socket and establishing the connection

// Now if we have an IPv4 based host
if (sAdrInfo->ai_family == AF_INET) {
    this->hostaddr = inet_addr(addrParsed);
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // Now we need to set these (address and port to our sockaddr_in variable sin)
    sin.sin_port = htons(remotePort);
    memcpy(&sin.sin_addr, &hostaddr, sizeof(hostaddr));
}
// Now if we have an IPv6 based host
else if (sAdrInfo->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
    this->hostaddr6 = inet_addr(addrParsed);
    sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET6;
    // Now we need to set these (address and port to our sockaddr_in variable sin)
    sinV6.sin6_port = htons(remotePort);
    memcpy(&sinV6.sin6_addr.s6_addr32, &hostaddr6, sizeof(this->hostaddr6));
}

// Now we need to connect to our socket :D
if (sAdrInfo->ai_family == AF_INET) {
    int resCon = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)(&sin), sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    if (resCon != 0){
        SERVER_ERROR("[SSH] failed to connect with error code: %d!\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
}
else if (sAdrInfo->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
    int resCon = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)(&sinV6), sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));

    if (resCon != 0){
        SERVER_ERROR("[SSH] failed to connect with error code: %d!\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
}

// Free our result variables
freeaddrinfo(sAdrInfo);

// Create a session instance
session = libssh2_session_init();
if(!session) {
    return -2;
}

/* Now to start the session. Here will trade welcome banners, exchange keys and setup crypto, compression,
 * and MAC layers */
rc = libssh2_session_handshake(session, sock);

if(rc) {
    SERVER_ERROR("Failure establishing SSH session: %d\n", rc);
    return -3;
}
```

What is wrong with the implementation that is generating the "Failure establishing SSH session" message with IPv6 stack?

Best regards,

Comment: What is `inet_ntop()` returning?  According to the man page, it returns `NULL` if a system error occurs, and sets `errno` to a value that indicates what the error was.   Seems like that would be useful information for you to know.

Comment: It is returning a large number. I re implemented using inet_pton and made a lot of changes. It seems to be solved. I will soon post here the solution.